# How to loop a process

Tags: python

I am learning Python and I am trying to create a simple function to do the following logic:

1. Take two random numbers and random operation.
2. The user will insert the right results.
3. If the results correct, that system will take with another random number and random operation, and so on.

I did the following but my issue that it is not taking the results are input for the next operation. Can you please review my code and tell me what I did wrong?

```
import random

num = 1
while num < 100:
    x = random.randint(1,9)
    y = random.randint(1,9)
    opslist = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
    ops = random.choice(opslist)
    
    print(x,ops,y)

    if ops == '+':
        z = x + y
    elif ops == '-':
        z = x - y
    elif ops == '*':
        z = x * y
    elif ops == '/':
        z = x / y

    result = float(input("Please insert the result: "))
    if result == z: x = z
    print(z)
    num = num+1
```

Comment: Move `x = random.randint(1,9)` in front of the loop, so it runs only once, and then `x` is kept from the end of the loop.

Comment: can you elaborate on this `I did the following but my issue that it is not taking the results are input for the next operation.` You want the result `x` to be one of the integers for the next operation?

Comment: You also don't need `num` at all, just use `while True:` to create an infinite loop.

Comment: "can you elaborate on this I did the following but my issue that it is not taking the results are input for the next operation. You want the result x to be one of the integers for the next operation?" - Yes that is what I need.

Comment: So you want ```x```to be your following integer but at the next operation you have this line ```x = random.randint(1,9)``` so your ```x```becomes a random number

Comment: Do what @tevemadar says this is your solution since you're gonna pick ```x``` randomly once.

Comment: Please show the input and the output for your program and also the expected output

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as tevemadar mentioned in the comments, to move `x` out of the loop, so that a random number is only assigned to it once before the loop. Every next value of `x` will be from the previous result if the input matches the result. You can then use an inline if to see if the result is equal to what the user has entered and then use it as the value of x or else pick another random number:

```
x = z if result == z else random.randint(1, 9)
```

Also, I would recommend moving the `oplist` initialization outside the loop to only initialize it once. Also, using a `for` loop will get rid of the unnecessary `num` variable.:

```
import random

opslist = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
x = random.randint(1, 9)

for i in range(100):   
    y = random.randint(1, 9)
    ops = random.choice(opslist)
    
    print(x, ops, y)

    if ops == '+':
        z = x + y
    elif ops == '-':
        z = x - y
    elif ops == '*':
        z = x * y
    elif ops == '/':
        z = x / y

    result = float(input("Please insert the result: "))
    print(z)

    x = z if result == z else random.randint(1, 9)
```